# Bind one Vue data object to another value inside the same data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So this is my problem, how can I bind the navbar dashboard entries title to the strings object's dashboard string?

The reason I want to do this is because I'm later on translating the strings object to various languages, so I need the navbar entries to be based on the strings data so that they all get updated automatically as I change the language of the strings inside the strings object.

```
const data = {
    navbar: {
        active: false,
        entries: {
            dashboard: {
                title: "BIND THIS STRING"
            }
        }
    },
    strings: {
        "dashboard": "TO THIS",
    }
};
// new Vue vm created after this
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the vue-i18n project I mentioned in your other question, this will be done for you when you change the locale.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an easier solution to my problem than involving yet another project in it. I'll look into i18n if there's no good way of doing this though so your answer is still noted and appreciated. :)

Comment: Understood. In this case you would probably want to use computed values  based of the `strings` property.